# Lumen POST Issue

Tags: php, post, lumen

I'm working on setting up a quick REST service with Laravel Lumen.  My very simple route list:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'v1', function() use ($router){
    $router->get('status', function(){
        return  "ready";
    });

    $router->post('reading', function(){
        return "Hello";
    });
});
```

I installed https://github.com/appzcoder/lumen-route-list and when I run it, I see my two routes.  When I issue my POST from my client (via C), which is:

```
   #define POST_THING  "POST /v1/reading HTTP/1.1\r\n"\
                       "Accept: */*\r\n"\
                       "Refer: exampledomain.ca\r\n"\
                       "Accept-Language: */*\r\n"\
                       "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"\
                       "Accept-Encoding: */*\r\n"\
                       "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n"\
                       "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"\
                       "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"\
                       "key=101abc\r\n"\
                       "Content-Length: 11\r\n"\
                       "\r\n"
```

I get back a 400:

> [02/Mar/2018:08:51:43 -0500] "POST /v1/reading HTTP/1.1" 400 3170 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36"

and from my client I get:

> 400 Bad Request
>
> Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not
>   understand.(Shortened)

The GET route works fine and I get "ready", before I try and preform the POST, I'm I doing something wrong?

Thanks
D

Comment: Do you really send 11 bytes of content as you specified in the header `Content-Length`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue!  I changed the POST to:

```
   #define POST_THING  "POST /v1/reading HTTP/1.1\r\n"\
                       "Accept: */*\r\n"\
                       "Refer: exampledomain.ca\r\n"\
                       "Accept-Language: */*\r\n"\
                       "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"\
                       "Accept-Encoding: */*\r\n"\
                       "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n"\
                       "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"\
                       "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"\
                       "Content-Length: 10\r\n"\
                       "\r\n"\
                       "key=101abc\r\n"
```

Now it works fine!  Hopefully this helps some other people running into the same issue.